# How to obfuscate API KEYS in AndroidManifest Android

Tags: android, proguard

I discovered `ProGuard` and I managed to get my code obfuscated. It works. Amazing tool.

But what ProGuard didn't obfuscate is the `AndroidManifest.xml`. I have a Google Maps API Key in my Manifest.

I "secured" this API KEY in Google Developer Console using my package name and SHA-1 fingerprint.

Is it recommended to obfuscate the api key in Manifest anyway? If so, how can  I achieve this with `ProGuard`?

Comment: May you try using Dexguard on your Constants.java file or 'strings' resource file?

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your google key into .xml file. Never place restricts strings into AndroidManifest file
2. Try using [Dexguad](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/dexguard)

On your Dexguard file, use the commands bellow

-encryptassetfiles res/values/**

(if you are using gradle job to get your environment parameters)

-encryptstrings class my.package.Environment.class

regards.